# Função javascript não defenida após $.getScript('');

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, mvc

Preciso carregar um ficheiro .js após uma chamada ajax. Estive a procurar e encontrei o `$.getScript('')` para chamar o meu ficheiro, ele abre, corre tudo bem, porém as funções definidas nesse ficheiro não estão a ser encontradas.

tenho uma função de clicklistener definida assim:

```
var record = $('#record');

record.onclick = function () {

            startTimer(1);
            mediaRecorder.start(50);
            console.log("recorder started");

        }
```

quando eu clico no botão com o id `record` nada acontece. Já experimentei colocar um nome nesta função e chama-la no botão:

```
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:startRecord();" id="record">Record</button>
```

mas também não foi reconhecida. Qual é a técnica correta para fazer o que quero?

Nota: Eu não coloco logo o script na página (antes do ajax call) pois preciso de valores e elementos DOM que resultam dessa chamada. Estou a trabalhar em MVC, a chamada ajax está numa razorView retorna html resultante de um controller

Comment: Talvez você deva transportar o bind para o "done" ou success do getScript.

Comment: A solução foi estranha. Coloquei `document.querySelector('#record');` em vez de `$('#record');`. Reparámos que o objeto devolvido era diferente de acordo com cada tipo de 'selector'. Alguém sabe explicar a diferença? fiz uma questão aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/258737/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-id-e-document-queryselectorid

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que você não está grantindo que o script foi carregado e ou está esquecendo de inicializar algo, se for só o primeiro caso isso deve resolver:

```
  <button type="button" id="record">Record</button>
```

Bind no evento done do $.GetScript('')

```
    $.getScript( "seu_script.js" )
    .done(function( script, textStatus ) 
     {
       $('#record').click(function(){
        mediaRecorder.start(50);
        console.log("recorder started");
       });
     });
```