# Qual é a diferença entre $('#id') e document.querySelector('#id')?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Não é suposto obter o mesmo resultado usando um método ou o outro? Eu adicionava um *listener* `oncick` e só usando o segundo método conseguia efectivamente declarar o *event listener*. Porquê?

```js
var record = document.querySelector('#record');

record.onclick = function(){

alert("Entrou!");

}

var record2 = $('#record2');

record2.onclick = function(){

alert("Não vai entrar!");

}
    <!--UPDATE-->
    var record3 = $('#record3');
record3.on('click', function(){ alert('Vai entrar sim!'); });
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <button type="button" id="record">Record</button>
    <button type="button" id="record2">Record 2</button>
    
    <!--UPDATE-->
    
     <button type="button" id="record3">Record 3</button>
```

Comment: O primeiro você utiliza o alias para uso do jQuery, enquanto que no segundo utiliza o DOM com JavaScript somente.

Comment: e que diferença isso faz a nível do `onclick`?

Comment: Se você criar um [mcve] com o comportamento descrito ficará mais fácil inferirmos o que está ocorrendo.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss feito!

Comment: @ihavenokia se eu não me engano (posso estar errado pois nunca testei), você está tentando usar o `jQuery` para selecionar, e o onclick do `JS` para clicar, no `jQuery` seria apenas `$('#record2').click(function(){})`

Comment: `record2.on('click', function(){ alert('Vai entrar sim!'); });`

Comment: Adicionado o exemplo acima ao fiddler

Comment: corrigido, e funciona!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O primeiro você utiliza o *alias* para uso do jQuery, enquanto que no segundo utiliza o DOM com JavaScript somente.

```js
var record = document.querySelector('#record');
record.onclick = function(){
alert("Entrou!");
}

var record3 = $('#record3');
record3.on('click', function(){ 
alert('Vai entrar sim!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<button type="button" id="record">Record</button>
<button type="button" id="record3">Record 3</button>
```

O que você errou foi misturar o jQuery ao JavaScript. Enquanto você pode se misturar, é importante entender que o jQuery e o JavaScript nativo se referem aos elementos DOM de forma diferente. Aqui você deve estar ciente de que `record`, `record2` e `record3` não são a mesma coisa. Um é um elemento DOM e o outro é um objeto jQuery que contém um valor.

```js
var record2 = $('#record2');
record2.onclick = function(){
  alert("Não vai entrar!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="record2">Record 2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não funciona pelo simples motivo do retorno de cada função:

```
document.querySelector('#record'); // retorna um [object HTMLButtonElement]
$('#record2');  // retorna um [object Object]
```

Para funcionar da forma correta, você precisa tratar da forma correta:

```js
var record = document.querySelector('#record');
record.onclick = function(){
  alert("Entrou!");
}

$('#record2').on('click', function(){ 
  alert('Vai entrar sim!'); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
<button type="button" id="record">Record</button>
<button type="button" id="record2">Record 2</button>
```